# Getting only first row of data by factor in R

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I have data like this :

```
Code  X    Y   Z
1     12.2 3.3 3.1
1     125  2   1
1     89   26  03
2     54   15  26 
2     89   26  65
3     26   56  15
3     4    2   5 
3     1    1   1
3     1    2   1
```

I want first row for each code. For example, I want something like this:

```
Code  X     Y    Z
1     12.2  3.3  3.1
2     54    15   26  
3     1     2    1
```

I know about `unique` but I donot know how it gets value, so I can not rely on this function. I request you please try to answer within the base packages available in the R.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 df[match(unique(df$Code),df$Code),]

# Code    X    Y    Z
# 1    1 12.2  3.3  3.1
# 4    2 54.0 15.0 26.0
# 6    3 26.0 56.0 15.0
```

`match` returns a vector of the positions for the first matches, which is what interest you here.

Comment: Or just `df[!duplicated(df$Code), ]`

Comment: does it produce only first top row always?

Comment: I have large data set.

Comment: @Neeraj: always the first match, so always the first row