# First row occurrence of each value

Tags: r

I have two varaibles a and amount sorted by a

```
a      amount

112    12000 
112    15000 
113    14000
114    18000
114    17000 
115    19000 
115    17000
```

I want the  first row occurrence of each value in a variable

```
output 

 a    amount
112  12000
113  14000
114  18000
115  19000
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042294/getting-only-first-row-of-data-by-factor-in-r or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451032/r-returning-first-row-of-group or http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/fast-ways-in-r-to-get-the-first-row-of-a-data-frame-grouped-by-an-identifier or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424762/efficiently-selecting-top-number-of-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column-in-a or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279582/select-only-the-first-rows-for-each-unique-value-of-a-column-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, head(.SD, 1), by = a]
```

Or a fast variant (contributed by @Symbolix)

```
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[1L], by = a]$V1]
```

Or use `unique`

```
unique(setDT(df1), by = "a")
#    a amount
#1: 112  12000
#2: 113  14000
#3: 114  18000
#4: 115  19000
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    slice(1)
```

Or use `summarise` with `first`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(a) %>% 
   summarise(amount = first(amount))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
aggregate(.~a, df1, head, 1)
#    a amount
#1 112  12000
#2 113  14000
#3 114  18000
#4 115  19000
```

Comment: I suspect avoiding `.SD` to be faster `dt[ dt[, .I[1], by = a]$V1 ]` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `duplicated` which would give you the duplicated values. You can ignore them with `!` operator

```
df[!duplicated(df$a), ]


#   a amount
#1 112  12000
#3 113  14000
#4 114  18000
#6 115  19000
```

Or

you can also use `match` along with `unique`

```
df[match(unique(df$a), df$a), ]

#   a amount
#1 112  12000
#3 113  14000
#4 114  18000
#6 115  19000
```